# Comparing date with sysdate in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a column which is of "`DATE`" type and I want to run a query on it comparing it with sysdate.

But I am getting following error, Can someone please let me know what I am missing here?

```
SQL> select distinct file_name as r 
     from table_1 
     where view_day >= TO_DATE(SYSDATE-10, 'YYYY/MM/DD');

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Comment: If one of these answers helped you with the solution please green mark it.

Answer (score 18):

You shouldn't use to_date on a date, To_date is for casting a varchar to date, not a date.
If you do use the function to_date on a date, then oracle will refer to it as a string according to nls_date_format which may vary in different environments.
As @jonearles said, if you want to remove the time in sysdate then use TRUNC

Answer (score 6):

USE:

```
select distinct file_name as r 
from table_1 
where view_day >= TRUNC(SYSDATE-10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Error shows that a `VIEW_DAY` column is varchar so you need to convert DATE to String. Use `TO_CHAR` or convert `VIEW_DAY` to date type.

Comment: Nope. view_date is of DATE type

Comment: Thanks! you are right. The default date format for view_date and sysdate in my system were both set to DD-MON-YYYY. Changing the format to same helped!

Comment: @TopCoder You may want to use TRUNC instead of TO_DATE.