# wrong date insert into the datablock

Tags: oracle, oracle9i, oracleforms

My problem is related to Date type, I am using below code when I want assign a date to a column. 
D_REPORT := to_date(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM');

but sometimes I receive a date like 31/01/0013 12:24:36 !!

I don't know why sometimes year will appear like 0013 and it is just for few systems, even when I am using sysdate, same problem will occur for me.

I want to check with you, anyone else also having same problem? how I can solve it?
because even when I use to_date or just simply write sysdate same problem will happens for me and I don't know what is root cause of the problem.

I am using oracle form 6i and my database is oracle 9i.

Comment: See these (not exact duplicates, but same issue) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147393/comaparing-date-with-sysdate-in-oracle/9147562#9147562, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108022/to-date-function-with-sysdate/14108132#14108132, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108022/to-date-function-with-sysdate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `to_date` on a date (and `sysdate` is a date).

TO_DATE gets a `varchar2` as a parameter so oracle implicitly converts your date (sysdate) to a varchar2 according to NLS_DATE_FORMAT which may not be `'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'` in every environment.

If the NLS_DATE_FORMAT is 'DD/MM/YY HH:MI:SS AM' then you'll get year=0013, since what will really be happening is something like this:

```
SELECT  to_date(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YY HH:MI:SS AM'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
FROM dual;
```

So, you just need to insert `sysdate` and when you display it (convert it to a string) use `to_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')`

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/5806)

Comment: So you recommend me only use SYSDATE or to_date(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') when I insert my data? I dont want when I get query from my database it appear like 0013.

Comment: If your column's datatype is date then you **need** to insert just `sysdate` (it's already a date), no need to do the ` to_date(TO_CHAR(...`